# How to use <md-progress-linear> in AngularJS MD?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using [Material Design](https://material.angularjs.org/) in my AngularJS app and I want to add a progress bar while my page is loading.

MD uses [md-progress-*](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdProgressLinear) Directive to get a loading bar:

```
<md-progress-linear md-mode="determinate" value="..."></md-progress-linear>
```

In my app I tried to get loading progress complete on `$viewContentLoaded`:

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <md-progress-circular ng-if="determinateValue === 100" md-mode="determinate" value="{{determinateValue}}"></md-progress-circular>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.determinateValue = 0;
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
        $scope.determinateValue = 100;
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work and I do not get any error.

ps. the `<md-progress-linear>` tag is disappeared from the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, use `md-mode="indeterminate"` as your loading is binary and has only two states. get rid of the `ng-if` and use the `value` attribute bound to `$scope.determinateValue`. So:

```
        <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" value="determinateValue"></md-progress-circular>
```

I'd rename the `determinateValue` to something more precise and reflective also. Also the tag disappears cause the determinateValue is always at some point being assigned to `100` ie your content is loading